# UserControl.InputBindings handles mouse event - surrounding listbox item is not selected

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user controled defined in my view:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding MyCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

This UserControl is rendered inside a listbox item.

When I click my user control, the command should be executed, but the listbox item should also get selected. I believe it's caused by the fact that the mousebinding handles my leftclick event, so the listbox will never get it.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I don't want to use code behind on my view.

Comment: Maybe it's a style issue. Try explicitly setting the background and foreground of your usercontrol based on the values of the ListBoxItem that contains it.